# json.Marshal returning weird values

Tags: go

I want array of json from sql rows. when i try to do marshal on each struct after scanning each row, its returning weird values like [123 34 105 100 34 ..]

```
type Org struct {
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

res, err := db.Query("select id,name from organization")
if err != nil {
    // fmt.Print("err in query")
    panic(err)
}
// var orgArray []Org
defer res.Close()
for res.Next() {

    var org Org
    fmt.Println(&org.Id, &org.Name, "PRINT ADDRESS BEFORE SCAN")
    
    //  0xc0001c0648 0xc0001c0650 PRINT ADDRESS BEFORE SCAN

    err = res.Scan(&org.Id, &org.Name)
    fmt.Println(org.Id, org.Name, org, "PRINT VALUES AFTER SCAN")
    
    // 1535 TestOrg {1535 TestOrg} PRINT VALUES AFTER SCAN

    b, err := json.Marshal(org)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(b)
    //[123 34 105 100 34 58 49 53 51 55 44 34 110 97 109 101 34 58 34 98 114 97 110 100 32 69 104 71 74 89 34 125]
}
```

whats the problem here?

Comment: Those are the bytes, convert `b` to `string` and print that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json.Marshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) returns a byte array - `[]byte`.

The `Println` prints `b` out as such. The array of integers (byte values) you see is how byte arrays are printed out in Go.

Use `string(b)` to print a string. `fmt.Println(string(b))`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`json.Marshal` response is bytes array, convert to string before printing

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Abc struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
    B string `json:"b"`
}

func main() {
    d := Abc{A: "aaa", B: "bbbb"}

    a, _ := json.Marshal(d)

    fmt.Println(string(a))
}
```